# c# prevent closing form by notifyicon

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications

I want my application to hide when the user want to close it.

after that by clicking on notifyicon the form will be shown .

Here is my coded : [form name = login]

```
private void login_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.hide();
}
```

and for notifyicon :

```
private void NIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Show();
}
```

but it doesn't work! What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add them to the event handlers also, try this on form_load

```
this.FormClosing += LoginForm_FormClosing;
notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += LoginForm_DoubleClick;
```

Then you can do like this

```
login form;
private void LoginForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    form.hide();
}
private void LoginForm_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form.Show();
}
```

Also read [this](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3336751/C-Tip-Placing-Your-C-Application-in-the-System-Tray.htm) it will be helpful.

Comment: What I read from your link makes the application to minimize ! But I want it to be like yahoo messager ! when you close your form it doesn't minimize ! It will shown by notifyicon !

Comment: The code that I wrote was for the closing event of the form... Try it

Answer (score 0):

You can try also [ShowInTaskbar property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private void LoginForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    e.Cancel = true;
    ShowInTaskbar = false;
}
private void LoginForm_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowInTaskbar = true;
    Show();
}
```

Comment: @user3171943, my answer is bad, `ShowInTaskbar` is redundant. Trying to reproduce, and fail. Try to reproduce you problem with new minimally modified form. Are you sure you subscribed to events and sure that `hide()` method is typing error and means `Form.Hide()`